# Cakephp Find query not functioning

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to Cakephp. I am facing problems in the find condtition. I have a table called TaskAssignment.
I have the following

```
 'SELECT `* FROM task_assignments WHERE task_id = 341 AND user_id = 1 AND role = 'admin' AND isDeleted = isDeleted;
```

I have created the following Cakephp query,

```
$this->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'TaskAssignment.task_id' => '341',
        'TaskAssignment.user_id' => '1',
        'TaskAssignment.role' => 'admin',
        'TaskAssignment.isDeleted' => 'TaskAssignment.isDeleted
    )))
```

But somehow this query is not functioning as required. Could anyone guide me in the proper direction.

Comment: This condition: `AND isDeleted = isDeleted` doesn't do anything - it's checking that a field value = the same field value, what is that condition actually for/supposed to do?

Comment: isDeleted can be true of false. the problem is somehow the app model before filter is adding the condition 'TaskAssignment.isDeleted' => false. So to remove that condition I am adding the above mentioned condition of 'TaskAssignment.isDeleted' => 'TaskAssignment.isDeleted'.

Comment: I think you've missed the point of my comment - the value of a given field is always equal to the value of _the same field_.

Comment: simply to remove the default condition

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$this->find('all', array(
'conditions' => array(
    'task_id' => '341',
    'user_id' => '1',
    'role' => 'admin',
    'isDeleted' => 'isDeleted'
)));
```

Comment: Please consider adding some detail to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since 'TaskAssignment.isDeleted' can either be true or false. I found a solution to the problem as follows:

```
$this->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'TaskAssignment.task_id' => '341',
        'TaskAssignment.user_id' => '1',
        'TaskAssignment.role' => 'admin',
        'TaskAssignment.isDeleted' => array(true,false)
    )))
```